# how to identify the dropdown which has the value 0 in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 7 dropdowns in the row and 20 rows are available in page. I need to find the dropdown which has value 0. Each drop down has similar Id like "'rowId'SelectedValue'ColumnId'".i hava an idea of iterating each drop down by forming its id in iteration. is there any other idea?

Comment: on the basis of selected value or set value?

Comment: On the basis of selected value

Comment: is there way to apply filter for values. i know for class, or tag names. How do we apply for Values?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through all of them and assign the correct one to a variable:

```
var $selector;
$("select").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
        $selector = $(this);
        return false;
    }
});

$selector.hide();
```

I don't know what should happen if more than one dropdown have a value of 0, so this just returns the first.

To use a `filter` to get the values, you'll want something like this:

```
$("select").filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).val() == "0"
}).hide();
```

Here's a little fiddle to show the filter: http://jsfiddle.net/npkgLLth/

Note that Filter seems to be the slower of the two by around 10%-15% in my version of Chrome, and 50% slower in IE: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-and-filter

Comment: Whenever you find yourself writing an `each()` loop with a conditional to extract part of an element set, consider using `filter()` instead, the resulting code will be shorter and clearer.

Comment: this is what i had in my mind. instead of iterating over all dropdowns i just wanted to know if there is any other filtering option.

Comment: Indeed, there is the overhead of an additional function call per iteration. However, it usually does not matter in the big picture, and it does make the code clearer :)

Comment: The test was a little unfair, as the correct input was the first in the DOM, so iteration would end. Moving it to the end improves things somewhat - doubtless there would be a crossover point where `filter` would become more efficient. http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-and-filter/2